# Error: The getter 'tokrethrow' isn't defined for the class 'Bloc<Event, State>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-packages

I had to do android compileSdkVersion 33 for a package. From it I started getting the error appearing below. What is the solution to this?[image]

Comment: maybe try a `flutter clean`

Comment: flutter clean doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

Remove/Comment-out Flutter_bloc from pubspec.yaml file and run flutter pub get. And then add flutter_bloc again and re-run flutter pub get.